# No such module ‘FirebaseUI’

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am receiving a “No such module ‘FirebaseUI’”

I have an app where I am trying to subclass from FirebaseAppDelegate and I am getting an error. I am using the docs at: 
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FirebaseUI/0.3.2/

============================================

The sample code in that link shows the following swift code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseUI

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FirebaseAppDelegate {

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    super.application(application, launchOptions);
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    return true
  }
```

============================================

My app has the following code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuthUI
import FirebaseUI

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FirebaseAppDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        return true
    }
```

in my Podfile I have the following:

target 'FBLogin' do

use_frameworks!

pod 'FirebaseUI'

pod 'Firebase'

end

I ran 'pod install' without issues.

============================================

I also downloaded the sample code at: 
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS

I searched for “FirebaseAppDelegate” and could not find a reference to that text in the sample code project.

Note that I had other components of FirebaseUI already working in my app. It wasn't until I tried to subclass from FirebaseAppDelegate that I started having build issues.